# How to change Tray icon color on Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: node.js, electron

In Electron, OSX has the IconTemplate.png to help you manage icon color across themes. How can I do the same for tray icons across different themes on Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: umm,  ok... `let tray = new Tray('./IconTemplate.png')`

Comment: boom show your snippet which may give proper reference related to your question.

Comment: That's what I did, for the snippet I posted the icon does not change on Ubuntu or Windows when the platform theme changes, but it does work on OSX.

Comment: Your example is just the creation of a new Tray icon, there is no expanding logic. Electron does only give a icon to the OS depending on the API of that OS, check [electrons tray_*.cc files](https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/80e6a64e47d2e4b6531631afd39c33ac653fd0bf/atom/browser/ui) for this. If you want to make logic based on the metrics of a theme, you need to check them via native node_modules, commandline or binding that read out those information. For example for [windows via C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.themecolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [...] After that you simply create a individual Tray based on that data. A c# binding library for node would be [edge-js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) and for electron the prebuild [electron-edge-js](https://github.com/agracio/electron-edge-js)

Comment: So, I need to look up theme details manually via child process or something and somewhere on each system returns the tray background color? Then I can decide on my own tray color based off of that?

Comment: that is correct ;)

Comment: Are there any examples of the best way to do this? This has to be a problem people have run into a lot. Any starting resources?